# Items appear in SXA scope but not in search results

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using Sitecore 9, and SXA 1.7

I have a search scope that searches for certain items whose template is "blog page", in the scope query, I'm searching using the template and location, and I do get the items requires as results.

However, when I use the Search result component in a page and give it the previously mentioned scope, it does not show me any results.

I do not know the reason for this, if anyone ran into anything similar I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: What is the location of those items?

Comment: in the SXA tree under Home/Media/Posts, The scope query search shows the items i'm looking for (when i'm writing the query), but for some reason it stopped working when i use it inside the "search result" component on a page. I think it's an issue with solr. I tried rebuilding the indexes but that didn't help

Comment: Be sure that your template inherits from **_Searchable** template (/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Search/Computed Fields/_Searchable).

Comment: I checked and made it inherit from _Searchable, but it didn't work. I tried restarting solr service, Rebuilding the indexes multiple times, and it still does not work. The query inside the scope shows the results, but using it in the search result component on a page doesn't show a thing. it's driving me crazy.

Comment: You need delete items and recreate again after assigning _searchable base template

Comment: What template are those items based on? I think the problem is that the template won't have rendering variant of Search result with field to show. That's why no results are shown. Can you pace Total count component somewhere near by Search Result? I think you will see expected number. Problem is that media items are not displayed as they are not "Pages".

Comment: I do have the same issue. Did you find answer for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried many of the suggested solutions in the comments, but at the end what fixed it for me was rebuilding the index, i'll list the things I needed to check first below:

- Make sure that your template inherits from _Searchable template (/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Search/Computed Fields/_Searchable).
- Make sure that you set that inheritance in the template first, then create the items you need, and check the search result for the new items.
- Try rebuilding your indexes, from the Sitecore launchpad, in configurations, indexing. (this is what worked for me)
- Make sure that your search result component has a rendering variant set to it, and that the rendering variant is reading the correct fields from your items.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to build the query for search scope without `sitecore_sxa_master_index` core (`website_master_index` will be used instead).

If none of the solutions above solve your issues, probably you missed the "Create SOLR SXA cores" part during your SXA installation process:

1. Duplicate the core directory created for `sitecore_master_index` (or `company_name_master_index`) twice and rename it to:

   ```
    • sitecore_sxa_master_index
    • sitecore_sxa_web_index
   ```
2. In those two folders, remove everything besides the "conf" directory.
3. On the Solr web interface, click Core Admin, and click Add Core to add `sitecore_sxa_master_index`. Do the same for `sitecore_sxa_web_index`
4. Populate schema and rebuild indexes