# SXA search results not working

Tags: sxa, content-search

I have an issue exactly similar to this

[Items appear in SXA scope but not in search results](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12281/items-appear-in-sxa-scope-but-not-in-search-results)

and here is my sitecore log

```
    876 14:32:27 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/aggregator
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Processing.AsyncPoolScheduler`2..ctor(IAsyncProcessingPool`1 pool, IXdbContextFactory xdbContextFactory, ExpandOptions options, Int16 maxBatchSize)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.InteractionAggregationAgent.<ExecuteCoreAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.Agent.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<ExecuteAgentAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.AsyncBackgroundService.<RunAsync>d__26.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteGetAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient.<Refresh>d__4.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.IO.IOException
Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Source: System
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)





ManagedPoolThread #5 14:32:31 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #5 14:32:31 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
13504 14:32:35 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerLiveAgent
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteGetAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient.<Refresh>d__4.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.IO.IOException
Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
Source: System
   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)





16704 14:32:36 WARN  Results endpoint exception
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Extensions.ItemExtensions.FirstChildInheritingFrom(Item item, ID templateId)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.FacetService.GetFacetItems(IEnumerable`1 facets, String siteName)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Extensions.FacetExtensions.ApplyFacetFilters(IQueryable`1 query, NameValueCollection queryString, Coordinates center, String siteName)
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Search.Services.SearchService.GetQuery(String query, String scope, String language, Coordinates center, String site, String itemid, String& indexName)
   at Sitecore.XA.Feature.Search.Controllers.SearchController.GetResults(String v, String q, String s, String l, String g, String o, Int32 e, Int32 p, String sig, String site, String itemid)

22532 14:32:41 INFO  Cache created: 'ExperienceAnalytics.Sites' (max size: 1MB, running total: 3714MB)
ManagedPoolThread #2 14:32:41 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #2 14:32:41 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
```

can anyone understand what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This bit:

```
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions
   at Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Extensions.ItemExtensions.FirstChildInheritingFrom(Item item, ID templateId)
```

especially `FirstChildInheritingFrom` might mean that SXA has not been properly installed (e.g.: some templates are missing).

Answer (score 0):

Exception `System.NullReferenceException, Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` means that you are using default host header of Sitecore instead of host header of your SXA site.

To solve your problem:

1. Browse using your SXA Host Header Url.
2. Check that Solr Cores `sitecore_sxa_master_index` and `sitecore_sxa_web_index` exist.

If they don't, create them using the following command:

```
solr create_core -c new_core -d basic_configs
```

3. Populate schema and rebuild index.