# Accordion item type template items not indexing in Sitecore search as well as Solr search

Tags: sxa, solr, indexing, sxa-search

I am working on `SXA search` in Sitecore I found something strange, content or data of composite rendering child items like accordion item templates types items are not indexing.

I added `_searchable` template inheritance to all base templates of accordion templates (`Accordion, Accordion Item, Accordion folder`) It also didn't work.

I tried to query the template and accordion item in the Solr dashboard and also tried to search accordion item template type item in the Sitecore search box, but items are not showing there.

Accordion item templates type item also not appearing in scope query.

If you have any idea how the accordion child item of the accordion item template will be indexed in `SXA`?

I tried the below references. didn't work for me.

Ref:

1. [How can I modify SXA search component to search also in the Accordions content?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11758/how-can-i-modify-sxa-search-component-to-search-also-in-the-accordions-content)
2. [SXA search - Accordion Items are not shown up after indexing even in scope query when we provide template name](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25238/sxa-search-accordion-items-are-not-shown-up-after-indexing-even-in-scope-query)

Comment: Did you also try this? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12281/items-appear-in-sxa-scope-but-not-in-search-results

Comment: May be you can check basic things like 1. your template is not in ExcludeTemplates list 2. You can try to add your template in IncludeTemplates list 3. Check your index Crawling, if your item path is outside of crawling range then it won't include in search 4. rebuild the index

Comment: Thanks Sumit and Rinku for your quick response. Your suggestions didn't work for me but i got idea.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you can check the below things to make it work.

1. Check if your template inherits from `_Searchable` template (`/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Search/Computed Fields/_Searchable`). That I think you have already done.
2. Make sure you set that inheritance in the template first, create the items you need, and check the search result for the new items.
3. Populate schema and rebuild indexes.
4. Ensure that your search result component has a rendering variant set to it and that the rendering variant reads the correct fields from your items.

Comment: Thanks @SumitBhatia and Rinku Jain for your quick response. Your suggestions didn't work for me but i got idea.  Composite rendering child items( of types Accordion Item, Carousel Slide, Flipside templates etc..), templates, placeholder keys are excluded by default, so this is reason these items types are not indexing in Sitecore Search or Scope query, Solr search. I commented few lines in config name "Sitecore.XA.Feature.Composites.config" and it started indexing. Please see link where  I have implemented https://www.mypiblogs.com/Blog/Details/81